# MVC application that can change firewall settings in Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, api, iis, firewall, rights

I want to make an MVC API application that can add / delete rules in the server's firewall.
The written code is functional (I use NetFwTypeLib) - I tested it in a winform application launched as an administrator. If I try to do a GET to the API that creates the rule in the firewall I get the following error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I assume that these are some rights that stop the execution of the code. I would like to know how I can modify these rights and whether assigning them increases the vulnerability of the server.
I tried to assign full rights to the web application in IIS Manager for the IIS_IUSRS user, but the result was unchanged.
Thank you and sorry for my English!

Comment: You already know the answer. For a web app to be similar to your WinForms app, change its application pool identity to an administrator.

Comment: You can alos set the identity of application pool to local system to enhance its permissions